# Job tracker and name node dont start with start-all.sh

Tags: hadoop

Im trying to install hadoop single-node but its not working correctly.

When I do `start-all.sh` **name node** and **job tracker** dont start.

Do you see in my files what can be be wrong so Im having this result?

**Result of hadoop jps command:**

14878 Jps

14823 TaskTracker

14605 SecondaryNameNode

14456 DataNode

**Result of start-all.sh command:**

```
admin@vm-sgd10:/usr/local$ start-all.sh
    starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-admin-namenode-vm-10.vd.uk.pt.out
    localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-admin-datanode-vm-10.vd.uk.pt.out
    localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-admin-secondarynamenode-vm-10.vd.uk.pt.out
    starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-admin-jobtracker-vm-10.vd.uk.pt.out
    localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-admin-tasktracker-vm-10.vd.uk.pt.out
```

**core-site.xml file:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://vm-10:10001</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/usr/local/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>vm-10:10002</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hadoop-env.sh file:**

```
 # The java implementation to use.  Required.
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
 # Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.
   export HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

**What appears in log:**

```
2015-03-10 12:24:11,698 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to vm-10/10.17.0.24:10001 $
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:1539)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getServer(RPC.java:530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:324)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try two things if you have not already.

1. First format the namenode again.
2. Start the daemons individually in this order, namenode, datanode, jobtracker and tasktracker. you can also include secondarynamenode.

Also, clear out your tmp folder. Which version of hadoop are you using?
-H

Answer (score 1):

Name node is not started as per your JPS output. First you need to start NameNode, check namenode log file . Also check the job tracker log files. I think looking at these two files will give you more information to debug.